# Django admin - admin inheritance

Tags: django, django-admin

When registering django admin, I inherited another admin, but I don't know why the model of list_display is changed.

Let me explain the situation in detail with code.

```
@admin.register(User) 
class UserAdmin(models.Model):
    list_display = [a.name for a in User._meta.concrete_fields]


@admin.register(Sales)
class SalesAdmin(UserAdmin):
    pass
```

According to the code above, SalesAdmin Admin appears to inherit from UserAdmin.
In this case, shouldn't list_display of User model appear in list_display?

I don't understand why the list_display of Sales Model comes out.
If I want to display the list_display of the Sales model while inheriting UserAdmin, shouldn't I have to redeclare the list_display as shown below?

```
@admin.register(User) 
class UserAdmin(models.Model):
    list_display = [a.name for a in User._meta.concrete_fields]


@admin.register(Sales)
class SalesAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = [a.name for a in Sales._meta.concrete_fields]
```

I did not redeclare list_display, but I do not understand whether it is automatically output as the list_display of the changed model. If anyone knows, please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the [`get_list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_list_display) method to return a list_display that is dynamic based on the current model.

FYI, your admin classes should inherit from `admin.ModelAdmin` not `models.Model`

```
@admin.register(User) 
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_list_display(self, request):
        return [a.name for a in self.model._meta.concrete_fields]


@admin.register(Sales)
class SalesAdmin(UserAdmin):
    pass
```